# Convert Nvarchar DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, date, format

Hi I have a column in my 'Users' table called 'PersonalDetails_DOB'.

The data type is a NVARCHAR(10) and the 'format' the data is currently in DD/MM/YYYY.

I want to change the format to YYYY.MM.DD or YYYY-MM-DD, how would I do this?

I have already tried a running a query in SQL:

```
 SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), PersonalDetails_DOB, 102) as
 'PersonalDetails_DOB' FROM Users;
```

Nothing happens and it doesn't change any date from e.g. 06/02/1967 to 1967.02.06

Comment: Your query is treating `PersonalDetails_DOB` as if it were a date, while it's a string actually. Best would be to really store it as a `DATE`. As long as it's stored as a string (`NVARCHAR`), you would either have to use string manipulation in order to swap string parts or convert it to date first before converting it into another string then.

Comment: @Zack You need to first update the values in date format and then you can change the data type of column. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Store dates as dates, not strings.  I recommend you pull the value as a date and not a string:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, PersonalDetails_DOB, 103) as PersonalDetails_DOB
FROM Users;
```

You are safer using `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(date, PersonalDetails_DOB, 103) as PersonalDetails_DOB
FROM Users;
```

To find the bad values, you can do:

```
select PersonalDetails_DOB
from users
where  TRY_CONVERT(date, PersonalDetails_DOB, 103) is null;
```

You can convert back a string if you want.

I would recommend that you fix the data structure.  This should work:

```
update users
    set PersonalDetails_DOB = CONVERT(date, PersonalDetails_DOB, 103);

alter users alter column PersonalDetails_DOB date;
```

Comment: So do i need to change the data type to 'date' instead of Nvarchar? that means i'll loose all of the data in the column? It is Nvarchar for a reason, can't remember why and changing it to DateTime will mess up alot of things within the Web App.

Also using your code I get the following error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @ZackAntonyBucci . . . Your data is messed up.  You will need to spend time fixing your data *and* your application if you want to use the date-of-birth.  Good lesson on why you want to use proper types to store data.

Answer (score 2):

You need two `convert()` function :

```
SELECT PersonalDetails_DOB, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, PersonalDetails_DOB, 103), 102)
FROM Users;
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @Zack Antony Bucci: Then your table contains data that doesn't match `DD/MM/YYYY`. This is why you should have stored the dates as dates and not as strings in the first place. I suggest you change your table design (rename the column, add a date column `PersonalDetails_DOB`, fill the new column with an update, delete the old column).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query to update the date values format and also their data type using SUBSTRING() function as shown below

```
declare @PersonalDetails_DOB NVARCHAR(10)
set @PersonalDetails_DOB = '13/10/2018' --dd/MM/yyyy

select SUBSTRING(@PersonalDetails_DOB,7,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@PersonalDetails_DOB,4,2) 
+ '-' + SUBSTRING(@PersonalDetails_DOB,1,2) 
         -- yyyy-MM-dd

create table Users(PersonalDetails_DOB NVARCHAR(10))
insert into Users values ('01/10/2018')
select * from Users --Before Update

--Updating date values
update Users
set PersonalDetails_DOB = (
    SUBSTRING(@PersonalDetails_DOB,7,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@PersonalDetails_DOB,4,2) 
        + '-' + SUBSTRING(@PersonalDetails_DOB,1,2) 
)where PersonalDetails_DOB is not null

select * from Users --After Update

--Change the datatype
ALTER TABLE Users
ALTER COLUMN PersonalDetails_DOB date;
```

You can find the live demo [**Live Demo Here**](https://rextester.com/OHFC85669)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should first set dateformat before conversion:

```
set dateformat dmy;
select PersonalDetails_DOB
    ,convert(nvarchar(10), cast(PersonalDetails_DOB as datetime), 102) as ANSI_DOB
    ,convert(nvarchar(10), cast(PersonalDetails_DOB as datetime), 120) as ODBC_DOB
from Users;
```